# Configuring systemd to allow daemon to set RT priority

Tags: priority, threads, systemd

I have a daemon that calls pthread_setschedparam() to set the thread priority. On a system using systemd (OpenSuse 12.1), this fails, because sched_setscheduler() returns EPERM.

From what I understand systemd doesn't use the permissions set in /etc/security/limits.conf any more where I used to be able to allow this.

How can I allow a deamon to change RT priorities when using systemd ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [systemd.exec(5)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html), then experiment with `LimitRTPRIO` and `LimitRTTIME` or `CPUSchedulingPolicy`, `CPUSchedulingPriority`, `CPUSchedulingResetOnFork` in daemon service file.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.